# Convert timestamp into custom format Laravel

Tags: php, timestamp, laravel-5.1

how to convert timestamp into following format `03 Dec 2015`

DB timestamp `2015-12-03 05:23:08`

this is what i tried

```
 <td>{{  date('d/m/Y', strtotime($user->created_at)) }}</td>
```

but i dnt know how to get month with 3 words . pls advice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<td>{{  strftime("%d %b %Y",strtotime($user->created_at)) }}</td>
```

Or,

```
<td>{{  date("d M Y", strtotime($user->created_at)) }}</td>
```

Comment: That is plain php, `created_at` is a `Carbon` object here if you use the `protected $dates` array in your class. Even if you don't it is usually defaulted to a `Carbon` date object. You can just call `->format('d/m/Y')` like @Zoe Blair wrote in her answer.

Answer (score 4):

created_at should be an instance of carbon. Then you can do:

```
{{ $user->created_at->format('d M Y') }}
```

Comment: this only work on "created_at" only in laravel not for others

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to format it in the model for `laravel 6` and above using the below casting feature

```
protected $casts = [
   'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
   'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
   'deleted_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d h:i:s'
];
```

You can add any format you prefer in the $casts array